Avoid for table of table to mantain same memory allocation when inserted to another table
In Lua 5.3, I have a table t1 in which there is only a table, the latter table consisting only of a key [key] pointing to the value 1.
t1 = {{key = 1}}

My goal is to copy and insert the inner table to an empty second table t2, and then ONLY manipulate the values of the table inside t2. However, when trying to do so with the code below, the table in the table t1 is also affected, which is not wanted. I am guessing this is because {key = 1} is a table that in both t1 and t2 is pointing to the same place in memory, which is undesired. What is a recommended way to avoid this?
Thanks in advance.
local t1 = {{key = 1}}
local t2 = {}
table.insert(t2,t1[1])
t2[1].key = t2[1].key + 1
print(t1[1].key, t2[1].key)

Result:
2  2

Expected:
1  2


Because

Assignment, parameter passing, and function returns always manipulate
references to such values; these operations do not imply any kind of
copy.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1

I know that and it is not the question I asked. I wanted to know a good practice to achieve the result I wanted.

Instead of passing a reference to the table, use adding an element by its value manually t2[#t2+1] = {key = t1[1].key} That was the essence of the answer.
